# Установка CleverStack

Tags: javascript, grunt, bower

Подскажите пожалуйста как это установить https://github.com/CleverStack/cleverstack-cli
Как не пытался, сыпет ошибками

```
PS D:\projects> clever init cleverstack
(node:5400) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
(node:6296) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
Preparing for installation...
  └── Creating project installation path...
Installing Backend...
  ├── Installation path is D:\projects\cleverstack\backend...
  ├── Downloading and extracting node-seed...
  ├── Creating local configuration file config/local.json...
  ├── Installing NPM modules...
  └── Installing module dependencies...
✔  Backend installation has completed successfully!

Installing Frontend...
  ├── Installation path is D:\projects\cleverstack\frontend...
  ├── Downloading and extracting angular-seed...
  ├── Installing NPM modules...

Status @ 13.100m |   Installation Progress: [▒▒▒▒▒-----]  50 %   ┊   Installing: Frontend   ┊   Step: Installing NPM modules...   ┊   Step Time: 11.017m   ┊
PS D:\projects> clever server
(node:5612) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
CleverStack couldn't find a backend or frontend directory within D:\projects
PS D:\projects> cd cleverstack
PS D:\projects\cleverstack> clever server
(node:6368) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
(node:1208) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'utils'
Warning: Task "server" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: поставьте grunt

Comment: поставил, не помогло :(

Comment: обновите вопрос. покажите новые ошибки.